# How to copy Windows 8.1 updates files from one pc to another?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1

I just installed Windows 8.1 through the app store in my windows 8 machine. I have another machine that needs to be updated. I can't get the iso because I'm a single language user. How to move the 8.1 update files to the other machine without re-downloading?

Comment: Download the actual knowledgebase files manually.  They are on the Microsoft website.